# Inventory Stock Sales Channel Mageto 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, inventory, msi, manage-stock

So we have this query that keeps running and BlackFire is complaining about it and I'm wondering if I turn it off there will be any negative effects. We're not managing our own stock so I assume it would be fine.

It looks like so from the BlackFire profiler:

```
select ? from inventory_stock_sales_channel where (type = ?) and (code = ?)
```

Any ideas on if it's okay to turn off and the best way of going about turning it off?

Would it be as simple as just removing the modules like so:

```
"replace": {
    "magento/module-inventory": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-cache": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-catalog-search": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configuration": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-export-stock": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-export-stock-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-import-export": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-indexer": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-multi-dimensional-indexer-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-product-alert": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservations": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservations-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-sales-frontend-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-setup-fixture-generator": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-shipping": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-selection": "*",
    "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*"
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently I got a client who had no need for the MSI functionality and the standard functionality was fine. So far we haven't noticed any issues with removing from removing the MSI system. But it wouldn't surprise me if Magento removes the old stock system in a few update.

Comparing your composer replace with the one we currently go in deployment and looks like you might be missing a few modules if you want to remove the MSI functionality. I've attached our version below.

```
"replace": {
      "magento/module-inventory": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-advanced-checkout": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-bundle-product-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-cache": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-catalog": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-catalog-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-catalog-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-catalog-search": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-configurable-product-indexer": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-configuration": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-configuration-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-distance-based-source-selection-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-elasticsearch": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-export-stock": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-export-stock-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-graph-ql": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-grouped-product-indexer": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-import-export": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-indexer": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-low-quantity-notification-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-multi-dimensional-indexer-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-product-alert": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-requisition-list": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-reservation-cli": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-reservations": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-reservations-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-sales": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-sales-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-sales-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-sales-frontend-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-setup-fixture-generator": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-shipping": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-shipping-admin-ui": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-source-deduction-api": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-source-selection": "*",
      "magento/module-inventory-source-selection-api": "*"
}
```